Installing FireGiant HeatWave and wix extensions without Internet Connection
I want to install HeatWave (for Visual Studio 2019) from FireGiant on a server without an internet connection. I have seperately downloaded the file: FireGiant.HeatWave.Dev16.vsix on a different computer (with internet connection).
After double clicking on the *.vsix file it said it successfully installed HeatWave for Visual Studio 2019.
I created a new project as a console project, then i wanted to add new Wix Project, but there is nothing found.
Now my questions:

is it possible to do an install of the FireGiant.HeatWave.Dev16.vsix without an internet connection?
if the install without internet connection was successful, where is the heat.exe or wix.exe located?
i also want to install the wix extensions without an internet connection:
wixtoolset.sql.wixext, wixtoolset.ui.wixext, wixtoolset.util.wixext, which i have separately downloaded als *.nupkg files.
will i be able to install these *.nupkg files without an internet connection?
any help is appreciated

